# Meteor - Set the logged in user

Tags: javascript, authentication, meteor

How can I set the logged in user directly ? Something like

```
Picker.route('sayhi', (params, req, res) => {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const customUserId = getCustomUserId(req.headers);
    Meteor.setUserId(customUserId);
    console.log("hey I'm", Meteor.user());
    res.end('ok');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, this is the way it's internally done in meteor:

```
DDP._CurrentInvocation.withValue(new DDPCommon.MethodInvocation({
  isSimulation: false, userId: getCustomUserId(req.headers),
}), function () {
  // now things like Meteor.userId() work as expected
  // also every method called here will get the right userId
});
```

The only drawback of this solution is that it feels like using some kind of private API (or at least non-documented methods) that may potentially change over time. If you're not afraid of it, then I believe it's a way to go.

**Edit**

As @Guig mentioned in the comment, one will also need to `meteor add ddp-common`.

Comment: Thanks, it works very well so far. You also need to include the package DDPCommon in your Meteor dependencies

Comment: That's right. I should have probably put it in the answer as well.

Comment: I think the command is `meteor add ddp-common` :) Thanks for editing

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to allow an admin to *impersonate* users? If so then the [gwendall:impersonate](https://atmospherejs.com/gwendall/impersonate) package could be helpful to you.

```
Impersonate.do(userId, callback)
```

Or are you trying to have users authenticate in a different way? There are many existing packages for authenticating in a variety of ways.

Comment: By looking at the "impersonate" package it looks like this solution only works client side.